# Reusable UIView to fill common Information of an Array Items

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to develop an App that can track some Information from elements of an Array.
like:
array = ["Anna", "Charles", "Simon", "Criss"].

I've created a UITable View and I want to be able, when I click on the Name, to open a new View and fill following Information.
Adress:
Age:
Hobbies:

I am new in Swift and I don't know how to create this View.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` you can open `UIAlertController` and get thoese information.
For example, you have an Array

```
let dataArray =  ["Anna", "Charles", "Simon", "Criss"]
```

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Give title here", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Name"
            textField.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Address"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Age"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Hobbies"
        }
        
        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { alert -> Void in
            // TODO:- You will get that informaton here
            let first = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
            let second = alertController.textFields![1] as UITextField
            let third = alertController.textFields![2] as UITextField
            let fourth = alertController.textFields![3] as UITextField
            
        })
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil )
        
        
        
        alertController.addAction(saveAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

When you will click on `save` you will get that information in the closures.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Help Rashid! But what if I have a variable Array? I want to save this information from an Array that can have 30, 23, 10 elements and send this Information to another View